# R dplyr: summarise_each from an external lookup table?

Tags: r, dplyr

How would one solve the following toy problem using `dplyr`:

Take a data frame where each row contains at least two iris species separated by spaces:

```
mySpecies <- data.frame(
  Species=c("lazica uniflora setosa", 
        "virginica setosa uniflora loczyi",
        "versicolor virginica"))
```

I'd like to add 2 columns to 'mySpecies' where each row contains the mean of the Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width 
for only those species available in a separate lookup table: the iris dataset: `unique(iris$Species)`

The output of this example should be the mySpecies data frame with additional 'Sepal.Length.mean' and 'Sepal.Width.mean' columns containing the mean of those variables across each species that appear in iris$Species.

So the first row would just contain the Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width for 'setosa', because the other species names don't appear in `iris`. The second row, however, would contain the means of Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width across 'virginica' and 'setosa', because they both appear in the lookup table (i.e. `iris`).

Note that this is a toy example but my actual dataframes are quite large.

Comment: So what's the desired output for your example?

Comment: It is not clear how you want the output

Comment: Did you mean `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean), Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width) %>% bind_cols(., mySpecies)`

Comment: I've elaborated on the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. First, split up your string into individual species; then for each group: filter the rows that match, and compute the mean.

```
mySpecies %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    do({
        spec <- strsplit(as.character(.$Species), " ", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
        filter(iris, Species %in% spec) %>%
            summarise_each(funs(mean), Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

mySpecies= c("setosa", "loczyi", "virginica")

filter(iris, Species %in% mySpecies) %>%
    group_by(iris, Species) %>% 
    summarise(mean_width = mean(Sepal.Width),
              mean_length = mean(Sepal.Length))
```